Why is my original dataframe updating when I'm trying to edit a copy?
I've got a dataframe and I want to keep a "base" (original copy) which I can work from later. However when I use it and try to create a new dataframe, it's updating the original base copy too.
I've created a simple example which replicates my problem:
import pandas as pd

# create base df
base=pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]])

# simple function that does something to the df
def dosomething(df) :
    df[0]=[5,6]
    return(df)

# create a new df
new=dosomething(base)

# print new and base dfs
print(new)
print(base)

This gives the following output:
   0  1
0  5  2
1  6  4
   0  1
0  5  2
1  6  4

So both my "new" dataframe has updated as I'd expect, but also the "base" dataframe has (which I was expecting to stay as the original).
What am I missing?

You are not creating a copy. Try new = dosomething(base.copy()).

Where do you think a new/copy dataframe is being created?

Ahhhhh, thank you @Dogbert

Try the below code. It creates a literal copy of original object instead of just a reference to the original object.
import copy
import pandas as pd

base=pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]])

def dosomething(df) :
    df[0]=[5,6]
    return(df)

new=dosomething(copy.deepcopy(base))

print(new)
print(base)

